# OpenDaylight netconf build issue

Tags: maven, opendaylight

I've tried to build the netconf module following the instructions in the "Getting Started" sections of the [ODL wiki](https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/Main_Page).

Possible answers I've found:

1. Use correct 'settings.xml'.
2. Try to use different maven commands like:
   **mvn -Pq clean install;
   mvn install -DskipTests**

Unfortunately, all these variants didn't work for me.

So, I installed all necessary features like maven, got correct 'settings.xml', pulled netconf project from git and tried to build it using **mvn clean install**.
After that I got a lot of errors:

```
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for org.opendaylight.netconf:netconf-auth:1.4.2-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.opendaylight.odlparent:odlparent-bundle:pom:3.1.0 in https://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/public/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of opendaylight-mirror has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 11, column 13
```

...

```
[ERROR]   The project org.opendaylight.netconf:netconf-auth:1.4.2-SNAPSHOT (/home/ssavchen/netconf/netconf/netconf-auth/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for org.opendaylight.netconf:netconf-auth:1.4.2-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.opendaylight.odlparent:odlparent-bundle:pom:3.1.0 in https://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/public/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of opendaylight-mirror has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 11, column 13 -> [Help 2]
org.apache.maven.model.resolution.UnresolvableModelException: Failure to find org.opendaylight.odlparent:odlparent-bundle:pom:3.1.0 in https://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/public/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of opendaylight-mirror has elapsed or updates are forced
    ...
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to find org.opendaylight.odlparent:odlparent-bundle:pom:3.1.0 in https://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/public/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of opendaylight-mirror has elapsed or updates are forced
```

I've got that the issue is in 'odlparent-bundle', but I have no idea what to do with it. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: @StephenKitt Now I have the next issue: `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.17:check (check-license) on project netconf-auth: Execution check-license of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.17:check failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.17 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact com.sun:tools:jar:1.8.0 at specified path /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/../lib/tools.jar -> [Help 1]`

Comment: @StephenKitt 'java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_171"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-8u171-b11-0ubuntu0.18.04.1-b11)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.171-b11, mixed mode)'

Comment: @StephenKitt Oh, it's alive! Thank you for help. And sorry for bothering you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Maven repository still “remembers” that it failed to download the OpenDaylight artifacts which the build needs. To fix that, you can force updates with `-U`:

```
mvn -U clean install
```

You also need the full JDK rather than the JRE to build, so install that:

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk
```